# Why does setting up a Apple Developer account require a phone call?

Tags: developer-program

Why in this instance does setting up an Apple Developer account require a phone interview?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are enrolling your organization into Apple Developer Program. A phone call verification performed as a part of the process of enrolling your organization into the Apple Developer or Apple Developer Enterprise program.

You may be asked if you have the legal authority to enroll the organization and the intent of enrolling into Apple Developer program.